# RegExp matching only the first two entries within a capture group (whatever they happen to be)

Tags: javascript, regex, adobe-indesign

I'm currently working on an Adobe inDesign script, part of which is a function that finds measurements and picks them apart. I have a set of regexes that are run first using inDesign's `findGrep()` (not really relevant here), and then using the basic javascript `exec()` (because I need to do things with capture groups).

Now, I know that there are differences between these two regex engines, so I've been working to the capabilities of the much more limited JS engine (I think inDesign's scripting language is based on ECMAscript v3), but I've recently hit a problem that I can't seem to figure out.

Here's the regex I'm currently testing (I've broken up the lines to make it a little easier to read –

```
  ((?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|\d{4,}|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?:\.\d+)?)
  (?=-|‑|\s|°|º|˚|∙|⁰)
  (?:[-\s](thousand|million|billion|trillion))?
  (?:[-\s](cubic|cu\.?|square|sq\.?))?
```

- The first line finds numbers formatted in various different ways.
- The second line is a lookahead that makes sure I've reached the end of
  the numbers.
- The third line finds any multipliers that refer to that
  number.
- The fourth line is *supposed to* find any modifiers that go
  before the unit of measurement.

This is the sample text I was testing it on.

```
23 sq metres
45-square-metres
16-cubic metres
96 cu metres
409 cu. metres
12 sq metres
24 sq. metres
```

Now when I run the regex using inDesign's `findGrep()` it works as expected. When I run it using `exec()`, however, it does something odd. It will match the numbers and the multipliers just fine, but only "cubic" and "cu" get matched, the "square" and "sq" text is ignored.

To make things more baffling, if I reverse the order of these entries in the regex capture group (so it's `(?:[-\s](square|sq\.?|cubic|cu\.?))?` instead), then it only matches "square" and "sq" and not "cubic" and "cu".

Am I missing something really obvious here? I'm a javascript newbie, but I've been working with regular expressions in xslt for years.

```js
str = `23 sq metres
45-square-metres
16-cubic metres
96 cu metres
409 cu. metres
12 sq metres
24 sq. metres
`;
  patt = /((?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|\d{4,}|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?:\.\d+)?)(?=-|‑|\s|°|º|˚|∙|⁰)(?:[-\s](thousand|million|billion|trillion))?(?:[-\s](cubic|cu\.?|square|sq\.?))?/gm;
  while (res = patt.exec(str)) console.log(res);
```

EDIT:

So, here's the code as I'm trying to run it right now.

```
  str = `23 sq metres
    45-square-metres
    16-cubic metres
    96 cu metres
    409 cu. metres
    12 sq metres
    24 sq. metres
    `;
 var re = '(one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|(?:[0-9]|,|\\.)+)(?:(\\s?(?:-|–)\\s?)(one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|(?:[0-9]|,|\\.)+))?(?:[-\\s](thousand|million|billion|trillion))?(?:[-\\s](cubic|cu\\.?|square|sq\\.?))?'; 
    
patt = new RegExp(re);

while (res = patt.exec(str)) console.log(res);
```

If I try to run this on my machine, using the inDesign script, it fails to find anything with "square" or "sq", and when I run it in the code snippet view here it just freezes up. I'm guessing this is something to do with storing regexes as strings, yes?

Comment: Without seeing your Javascript code it's really hard to say what you're doing wrong. See https://regex101.com/r/0UpQhp/1. The one thing I will say is that `(?=-|‑|\s|°|º|˚|∙|⁰)` is utterly redundant since you capture the the separator in the non-capture groups which follow; see https://regex101.com/r/ByPgA3/1

Comment: @PatMagnetar - I added an executable script to demonstrate that all examples are matched as expected. You may want to change the script so that it produces your problem.

Comment: Thanks both for your suggestions. I've done some fairly hefty tidying up of the regex (a lot of it was inherited for something I made for the incredibly limited and finicky regex processor in xslt). 

I don't know why this would be, but it turns out that the problem was `\.?` – for whatever reason the processor was getting as far as there and then stopping. I wrapped the `\.?` in square brackets `[\.]?` and this fixed the problem.

Comment: Actually nope. That didn't work after all. I'll edit my original post to add some more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you right. If you want that your second code works in about the same way as your first code does, you probably need just to add `"gm"` in the RegeExp constructor:

```
var patt = new RegExp(re, "gm");
```

```js
str = `23 sq metres
    45-square-metres
    16-cubic metres
    96 cu metres
    409 cu. metres
    12 sq metres
    24 sq. metres
    `;
var re = '(one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|(?:[0-9]|,|\\.)+)(?:(\\s?(?:-|–)\\s?)(one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|(?:[0-9]|,|\\.)+))?(?:[-\\s](thousand|million|billion|trillion))?(?:[-\\s](cubic|cu\\.?|square|sq\\.?))?'; 
    
var patt = new RegExp(re, "gm");

while (res = patt.exec(str)) console.log(res[5]);
```

It gives me this output:

```
sq
square
cubic
cu
cu.
sq
sq.
```

### Update

I've changed `(cubic|cu\\.?|square|sq\\.?)` with `(cubic|cu\\.|cu|square|sq\\.|sq)` and it seems work in InDesign now:

```
str = "23 sq metres\n45-square-metres\n16-cubic metres\n96 cu metres\n409 cu. metres\n12 sq metres\n24 sq. metres";

var re = '(one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|(?:[0-9]|,|\\.)+)(?:(\\s?(?:-|–)\\s?)(one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|(?:[0-9]|,|\\.)+))?(?:[-\\s](thousand|million|billion|trillion))?(?:[-\\s](cubic|cu\\.|cu|square|sq\\.|sq))?'; 
    
var patt = new RegExp(re, "gm");

var msg = "";

while (res = patt.exec(str)) msg += res[0] + " : " + res[5] + "\n";

alert(msg);
```

[image]

Probably these `?` inside `(foo|bar)` are too much for InDesign script model.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm only really familiar with the scripting environment within inDesign, so the console stuff threw me off at first. This is encouraging and also confusing. This code seems to run precisely as I'd expect, but the exact same code run in the inDesign script still matches on "cubic" but not on "square". If I take out the instances of  `\\.?` then it works fine, but then of course it can't match "sq.".

Comment: So I have no idea why, but moving the `\\.?` to after the main capture group fixes that problem. So `(?:[-\\s](cubic|cu|square|sq)(?:\\.)?)?` instead of `(?:[-\\s](cubic|cu\\.?|square|sq\\.?))?`. I'm guessing it must be accidentally creating a reserved string that's used by indesign for something else. I'm marking it as answered, because you've at least confirmed that I wasn't doing anything wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad that you managed to solve the problem. But I suspect the condition `(cubic|cu|square|sq)(?:\\.)?` includes `cubic.` and `square.` (dot at the end) cases as well.

Comment: It will, yes, but I'm working within a corpus that has a standardised-ish syntax, so that isn't likely to come up, and won't have any negative effects if it does (famous last words, I know).